# Send response based on client request

Tags: bash, unix, networking, tcp, centos

I am trying to create a socket where the client receives a response based on their request, but I can not figure out how to achieve this on CentOS 7.

Until now I have the socket opened on port 100 and saving the client request in a file:

```
#!/bin/sh
nc -lvk 88.109.110.161 100 > port100.txt 2>&1
```

As client I send the request:

```
echo "Hello" | nc 88.109.110.161 100
```

And the file is populated with:

```
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on 88.109.110.161:100
Ncat: Connection from 88.109.110.161.
Ncat: Connection from 88.109.110.161:47578.
Hello
```

I want the client receive the response based on the query, if the request is Hello, then receive World, if World then Hello. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am on `macOS` now, so `nc` is probably slightly different on `CentOS 7` , but the example below should be helpful anyway.
If you want to change text passed to server script, that is then printed, try to modify it before redirecting it to a file. Use pipe to process it in `while` loop, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh
nc -lvk 127.0.0.1 8080 | while read in
do
  echo '------'
  if [[ $in == 'Hello' ]]; then
    echo 'World'
  elif [[ $in == 'World' ]]; then
    echo 'Hello'
  else
    echo "$in"
  fi
done | tee out.txt
```

Some client requests to test:

`echo 'test' | nc 127.0.0.1 8080
echo 'World' | nc 127.0.0.1 8080
echo 'Hello' | nc 127.0.0.1 8080`

Example output:

```
------
test
------
Hello
------
World
^C
```

Thanks to `tee` output will be also in `out.txt`. I've just redirected `stdout` for simplicity.